# Drupal 6 hook_menu with query string from l()

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hook, drupal-hooks

[Drupal 6]
My preprocess function is

```
function blogs_additions_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
    global $user;

    $op = '';
    $op .= l(t('Delete All My Blogs'),$_GET["q"],array('query' => 'delete=myBlogs'));

    $variables['profile'] = array('content_profile' => $op);
    $variables['user_profile'] = implode($variables['profile']);
}
```

and my hook_menu is

```
function blogs_additions_menu(){

    $items= array();

    $items['users/%?delete=myBlogs'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'delete_all_blogs',
        'access arguments' => array('access blogs additions'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

and my delete_all_blogs()

```
function delete_all_blogs(){
    global $user;
    $sql = "SELECT nid FROM node node WHERE node.uid='".$user->uid."'AND node.type='blog'";
    $result = db_query($sql);
    while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
        //print $sql;
        node_delete($row->nid);
    }
    drupal_set_message('test', 'test');
}
```

my users can view their profile like this
www.mysite.com/users/barack-obama

My hook doesnot seem to work. probably an error with the % used in the url. i dont know how to use it generic so that it works.

Comment: AFAIK, [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) does not accept/handle query parameters in its declarations, so you'd need to switch to something like e.g. 'users/%/blog/delete'. Also, if you use '%' wildcards, you'd usually want to pass them on to the callback function via the 'page arguments' entry - check the linked documentation for details.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely don't want:

```
$items['users/%?delete=myBlogs']
```

Instead, you probably want a callback that generates a confirmation form. [ ... emitting text "Are you sure you want to delete all blogs?" and then put the bit that actually deletes all blogs in the form's submit handler. This approach eventually gives you a place to check whether they have any blogs. ]

That form emitting callback could check for the delete=myBlogs variable being set within that callback if that was your design.

OR If you chose to put this form at a URL like 'user/%/delete-my-blogs' you could make that form a tab on the user's profile page. (Note singular user. You'd also need to change 
    'type'=>MENU_CALLBACK to 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 to make it a tab.

The % is a placeholder for their UID which would be passed to the callback via 
    'page arguments' => array(1),

I would also recommend changing the function name delete_all_blogs to blog_additions_delete_all_blogs() so that you don't collide with some namespace outside your module. One way to indiciate that this is a "private" function is to proceed with name with an underscore.

function _blog_additions_delete_all_blogs(){ ...

Learning about how to build the form / submit-handler is best done on a page like this:
http://drupal.org/node/751826

Comment: +1 - delete operations should never happen via a simple GET request. As for the confirmation form, Drupal offers a helper for that - see [confirm_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/confirm_form/6).

Comment: If I'm creating a form, where do I put it? In __blogs_additions_preprocess_user_profile__ OR __blogs_additions_menu__ OR __blog_additions_delete_all_blogs__ ??

Comment: Here's a good example... http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.admin.inc/function/block_box_delete/6

You could copy this function, change its name to correspond to your module, with ANY name and then make that function the callback for your tab. (i.e. the 'page callback' in your corresponding $items array)

Henrik's link shows the docs for confirm_form itself which'll explain the arguments. You'll likely need to change those a bit.

Comment: Since I use node_delete in function delete_all_blogs(){} , it seems we need to clear cache explicitly since the blogs still show up (though the node is deleted) in Views. How do I clear cache after node_delete?

Comment: best just google: drupal clear cache api :-) will that be sufficient to get my answer accepted? [-: